# How do I build a package against multiple resolvers

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How can I use `stack` to build and test a package against multiple resolvers?

Answer (score 5):

Set the resolver from the command line, overriding whatever is in `stack.yaml`:

```
stack --resolver lts-X.Y [build|test|exec|...]
```

A more persistent solution is to have different `.yaml` configurations in your repository, that you can select using `--stack-yaml`

```
stack build   # default is stack.yaml
stack --stack-yaml my-stack-lts-X.Y.yaml build
stack --stack-yaml my-stack-nightly-X-Y-Z.yaml build
```